# Goal combinations not working in Sitecore

Tags: xdb, fxm

I'm trying to show personalized banners on an external site using Sitecore FXM. The ext. site has 3 pages - Home, Services & Feedback. The banner is to be shown on Home page.

**Conditions:**
If user has visited Home page for the first time - Show banner1
If user has visited Services and Feedback pages - Show banner2

**Things I have performed in sitecore:**
Created 2 page filters - *services & feedback*.
Created 2 respective goals - *visited services & visited feedback*. These do not have any rules. Just plain goals.
Assigned goal to respective page filter using Manage FXM functions.

**Personalization rules for the banner rendering:**

> **Rule 1:**  (show banner2 if true)
>    where *visited services* is triggered
>   in past or current interaction and the elapsed days *is less than or
>   equal to 30* and the interactions *is greater than or equal to 0*.
>
> and where *visited feedback* is triggered in past or current
>   interaction and the elapsed days *is less than or equal to 30* and the
>   interactions *is greater than or equal to 0*.
>
> **Default:** (show banner1 if Rule1 is false)

**Output:**
In the ext. site, it always renders banner1. But if for rule 1 , if I just apply one condition (*visited services*), and then from home page, visit services page and back to home, it shows banner 2.

Where am i going wrong. Will multiple goals in a condition not work. Is there any other way.
It would be much easier writing a code in a controller rendering, but did not find any helpful information about how we can track if a user has achieved a goal, using code.  I'm a beginner and like to stay away from decompiling yet.

Using Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Hi Qwerty... Looks like rules are not working so its showing default banner, Can you Check Sitecore.FXM.config file located inside "Include/FXM" and see if setting name="FXM.ShareSessionsWhenPossible" is marked with "true".

Answer (score 2):

The combination you described should be entirely possible.

I encountered the same problem when implementing an FXM solution that triggered goals in Sitecore 8.2.

Essentially there is a bug with the Rule `OutcomeWasRegisteredDuringPastOrCurrentInteractionCondition`

The [solution in this ticket mentions](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/personalize-a-component-using-outcomes/8744) the fix in details for Sitecore 8.1 through to initial release of Sitecore 9.

You can find a github C# [example here.](https://github.com/Aceik/HandyHelixFoundation/blob/f5e8398fadf6698e6a9b6b6439a0d78a2476d82c/src/Foundation/Analytics/code/Condition/GoalWasTriggeredDuringPastOrCurrentInteractionCondition.cs) 
Once you implement the rule (with the fix) in C# you must edit the Sitecore item to point to the C# class you implemented.

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Visit/Goal was triggered during a past or current interaction
```

[My solution](https://github.com/Aceik/HandyHelixFoundation/blob/f5e8398fadf6698e6a9b6b6439a0d78a2476d82c/src/Foundation/Analytics/code/Condition/GoalWasTriggeredDuringPastOrCurrentInteractionCondition.cs) also made an additional fix so that when the rule is executed if the `Sitecore.Current.Session.Interaction` is null it will use `Tracker.Current.Contact` instead to execute the rule. It does this via `LoadHistorycalData` and `KeyBehaviourCache`.